# get data value of tag from click event in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

this is my code snippest.

```
<div class="pagination pagination-0" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<a class="jp-previous jp-disabled">«</a>
<a class="jp-current">1</a>
<span class="jp-hidden">...</span>
<a class="">2</a>
<a class="jp-next">»</a></div>
```

from this code i want fetch value of

```
<a class="jp-current">
```

through jquery. please note, id is restricted to use with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".jp-current").on("click", function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U6mBQ/

And if you don't need that just on click:

```
console.log($(".jp-current").text());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var val = $(".jp-current").first().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(".jp-current").click(function () {
    console.log(this.innerHTML); // or this.textContent
})
```

References

[.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

[.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)

[class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)